Python Print() Function Problem - Repeating a Printed Value on the same line
It's my first time on stack so if you notice that i'm not following a certain etiquette please point it out.
I do not get upset, do not worry about my feelings.
Not new to I.T. or programming but python was a long time ago for me and i'm getting back into it.
Obligatory intro's aside
PROBLEM : I understand how the print() function works, (at least i think i do).
I'm trying (as an exercise in learning) to print a value that repeats on the same line, but it's just not working.
TROUBLESHOOTING :
The following i understand...
print("HELLO") this is text string that results in
HELLO
Next... I understand that i can implement math functions
print(5x4)   this is a variable that results in
20
Now back to the text string, I understand i can repeat the text string as follows
print("HELLO"*5) and this will result in
HELLOHELLOHELLOHELLOHELLO
and if i wish to put them individually 1 line per hello i can use
print("HELLO"*5\n)
HELLO
HELLO
HELLO
HELLO
HELLO
THIS HOWEVER DOESN'T NOT WORK
print(5x4 * 5)   this results in
100
Because 5x4x5 =100  obviously
I would like it to output as follows
20 20 20 20 20
so
print(calulation then duplicate that answer by the amount of times i specify)
and i do realize i can do this
for i in range(5):
 print(20)


But i'm specifically looking to use the *5 instruction.
THE QUESTION :
Is it possible to use the format
print(5x4)
with the *5 (Multiplier)
in a one line statement to produce my desired outcome
I have tried
print(5x4*5)
print(5x4)*5
print[(5x4)*5]
and none of these seem to work, I've been racking my brain with this for approx 2 hours now.
I Understand that "print()" is used to print a TEXT STRING, but then.. it isn't always because print(5x4) is not a text string but an int, so i assumed it would be possible to just pop on *5 at the end and it should work.
Any ideas ?
I realize this is basics, i have searched the forum for the answer already, everything relates to either basic print("") Text strings or for loops (which i already understand), but i cannot find an answer to this specific issue (i'm suspecting it may not be able to be done, but if so, i don't understand why )
Thanks ahead of time

Is that what you want?
print(str(5*4) * 5)


Thank you, yes it is, I knew there was something like ... 'print(54)' and then obviously so that i don't get an error additional brackets had to be implemented, i did try 'print[(54)*5]' but that didn't work, so would you mind telling me why   "str" works when this is not a string but a mathematical calculation ?

So, the reason is data type of your "20". It can be a number: 20, or a text: "20". to convert to a certain data type, you can use dedicated built in function: str() for text.

Firstable, it's not a calculation anymore. It's the result. And str() is used to convert to a string.

Oh i see, You're converting Data Types before it outputs,  OK Thanks, Also i see you're new :P HI. Also how do i now mark this as Solved or Answered ?

A tick which becomes green)

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-data-types/
This looks usefull for you.

Thank you, i'll check it out. Since i'm new and after hitting the green tick, is there anything else i need to do on this question before leaving,  UpVotes or thanks , Does any of that stuff apply on this forum ?

OH, i see,  Yes, i tried to upvote , it said i wasn't yet worthy enough to upvote as i am a mere peasant and have not earned the right yet :P
